# Run out of ports calling my webservice from an android app

Tags: java, c#, android, asp.net, web-services

I have an android app and a C# web service

I am hosting my web service on IIS Express - nothing fancy just set up the directories.

My android app go to the web service gets the data and then displays it on the screen and repeats this as fast as it can go.

After a while my android app will throw the following exception:
"SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'Server was unable to process request. ---> No ports available in the range 10101 to 11100' faultactor: 'null' detail: org.kxml2.kdom.Node@41bdf340"
I have Googled around a bit and have not found anything that will help me.

I ran CurrPorts to watch the ports and it looks like every time the app calls the web service it is using a different port.
They all use port 80 but different remote ports.

The exception is being thrown on the following line of code
"SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) _envelope.getResponse();"

If I run IISReset the app will go back to getting data again until sometime thereafter to get the exception mentioned above.

Here is the code for my web service  which is just returning a comma separated string (it will do something more interesting just trying to get this working)

Web service code

```
[WebMethod]
public string GetDefaultResults()
{
    return "100,1,0,125.987,124.993,117.904,116.038";
}
```

Here is the code that my android app uses to call the web service.
I create a new thread and have it call this method then get the string value split it on ',' then put it in a few different TextViews

```
public class WebService implements Runnable{

    private static String NAMESPACE = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private static String URL = "http://mymachine/mywebservice/service.asmx";
    private static String SOAP_ACTION = "http://tempuri.org/";
    private String _soapAndMethod;

    private HttpTransportSE _androidHttpTransport;
    private SoapSerializationEnvelope _envelope;
    private String _methodName;

    public WebService(String methodName) {

        _methodName = methodName;
        _soapAndMethod = SOAP_ACTION + _methodName;
        SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, methodName);

        _envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        _envelope.dotNet = true;
        _envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        _androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
    }

    public String InvokeWebService() {

        String resTxt = null;

        try {
            _androidHttpTransport.call(_soapAndMethod, _envelope);
            SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive) _envelope.getResponse();
            resTxt = response.toString();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return resTxt;
    }
}
```

Any help would be great. Thank you to those who do respond. Is there some setting in IIS I need to change? Is there something I missed in my code?

Additional information:
When the server is responding the webservice request IIS creates a process called w3wp.exe and it this process that is running out of ports.

Doing in a little digging and experimentation the Webservice gets newed up each call to "GetDefaultResults". Which leaves w3wp.exe in a Listening state and they never go away until the iisreset is run.
Some time later it uses the remaining ports available and starts throwing that exception.

Why is it not reusing the same webservice instead of creating a new one each time.

If that is not possible what code do I write in the Webservice to close the connection after it is finished.  I put in a hack to cause it close after 5 seconds to see if that would work at least.
It does clean up w3wp.exe but after a short time I start getting this exception on the client.
"expected: START_TAG {http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/}Envelope (position:START_TAG @2:7 in java.io.InputStreamReader@41beb098) "
so this is not a work around but it helped me understand what the problem is a little better.

```
protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();

    base.Dispose(disposing);
}

void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Environment.Exit(1);
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your web service gets newed up is normal. For each request, a new instance of your web service will be instantiated to procces the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Webservice was referencing an api to get the values from then pass them over a webservice to the android app.

The problem was that every time the webservice was being called a new reference would be created to the api and after the request was sent it would never close out the port. As soon as I stopped referencing the api everything worked.
A cludge to get this to work is I had the webservice monitor a folder and send the data in the file that was last created. Then created another program to attach to the api and output the data to that folder.  Not the most elegant solution but it works as a proof of concept for what I am doing.
Still not entirely sure why the Webservice was never closing the port and I am suspect that the Webservice could not dispose of the reference to the api but I am not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

If you failed your first request, you might need to enable IIS Express to allow external connections. In your case, it looks like it only failed after running for a while.

In your question, I see that you

1. "go to the web service gets the data and then displays it on the screen and **repeats this as fast as it can go.**
2. did not call "close" on HttpTransportSE

You might be running out of local ports. Are you reusing the connection on all your requests? If not, try to close it when you are done.

Comment: The only thing I can find on the android side is the following:
 try {
            _androidHttpTransport.reset();
            _androidHttpTransport.getConnection().disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
  
Which I tried but I get the same exception.  Somewhere else they said that is what gets called when the function goes out of scope so it makes sense that it is not fix the problem.

Comment: Can you confirm if the error was coming from the server side or client side? When you get this error from the client, can you still call into the web service from another device? Maybe run a quick netstat to see if there were actually a lot of ports still open between port 10101 to 11100?

Comment: I am fairly sure it is the Server having the issue. I can run the app until I see the problem.  Leave the app running which is just catching all the exceptions and does not update I then run IISReset on the server. Once the server comes back up the app starts updating again.  Netstat shows that lot (more than I can scroll worth) of connections using port 80 on my machine all in TIME_WAIT.  It seems like the server is not closing the connection but the server code can't get much simpler.

Comment: Just to try to prove it with more certainty i started an emulator and my phone running and they both see the problem and see a lot of connections over port 80

Comment: Is hosting on IIS an option? At least you can confirm that it's a problem with IIS Express. The IIS Express was mostly meant for developers to develop and test applications. If you would eventually deploy to IIS, it helps to know that it's just a problem with Express.

Comment: Just re-read your comment. You said you run the app on both the emulator and your phone, if there is a problem with the client code, both would experience the same problem. What if you run the app just on the phone until you see the problem, and then try to access the same web service using another device, would it fail on another device immediately (indicate a problem on the server side) or after a while (a problem on the client side).

Comment: The fact that you are see a lot of connections on the server with local port 80 and different remote ports (you didn't specify, but it's probably the same IP address of your phone) indicates that there are a lot of open connections between your client and the web service. Check the remote port number, is it in this range: 10101 to 11100? I would go back to your client code and make sure it is indeed closing the connections.

Comment: Actually in your case, you are calling the web service as fast as you can, you might be better off trying to reuse the same connection. Also Your WebService class on the client side seems odd, How is InvokeWebService getting called?